# Make Flutter DropdownMenu Smaller

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, height

I'm attempting to reduce the height of a Dropdown menu, I have tried in this way:

```
SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: DropdownMenu<String>(
                        // inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(alignLabelWithHint: ),
                        
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                            isCollapsed: true
                        ),
                        dropdownMenuEntries: [
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: "Name - First", label: "Name - First",
                              style: ButtonStyle(textStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith((states) => TextStyle(fontSize: 10) ))),
                        ],

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

To reduce its height but the result is the following. How can I easily make the dropdown menu smaller?

[DropdownManu Height change attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGxWn.png)

I was expecting to make the Dropdown manu smaller

Answer (score 6):

You can control the height of dropdown menu using the `constraints` property in the InputDecorationTheme.

```
DropdownMenu<String>(
          dropdownMenuEntries: const [
            DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
              label: 'One',
              value: 'one',
            ),
            DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
              label: 'Two',
              value: 'two',
            ),
          ],
          hintText: 'Select',
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            isDense: true,
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const 
             Size.fromHeight(40)),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Make sure to adjust the content padding accordingly.

Comment: This approach is the one that is actually working, 
https://imageupload.io/hjNnxlQeD9tHrdL
the only problem is that the icon on the right is now moving toward the bottom, how can I move it in the middle again?

Comment: It works but I find setting isDense makes no difference.

Comment: @MarcoManzi You can use `Transform.translate` to fix the icon position, see my addon answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77834026/9872288

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by `Narendra Bhatt`, you can fix the placement of the drop down arrow icon with `Transform.translate`:

```dart
trailingIcon: Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(3, -5),
  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I See you are wrapping the container with sizedBox to reduce its size, that is not a good way, you can provide height or width directly to the container if you want to reduce its size.

Now talking about your question, if you just want to reduce you select menu height you can define menuHeight inside of the DropdownMenu and it will give you your desired results.

Here's your code

```
Container(
          height: 30.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: DropdownMenu<String>(
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(isCollapsed: true),
            // Here update this
            menuHeight: 50, 
            dropdownMenuEntries: [
              DropdownMenuEntry(
                value: "Name - First",
                label: "Name - First",
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  textStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
                    (states) => TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DropdownMenuEntry(
                value: "Name - Second",
                label: "Name - Second",
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  textStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
                    (states) => TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in container instead of sizedbox

```
container(
                    width: x,
                    height: y ,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: DropdownMenu<String>(
                        // inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(alignLabelWithHint: ),
                        
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                            isCollapsed: true
                        ),
                        dropdownMenuEntries: [
                          DropdownMenuEntry(value: "Name - First", label: "Name - First",
                              style: ButtonStyle(textStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith((states) => TextStyle(fontSize: 10) ))),
                        ],

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```